# OracleDB open source way to ingest CDC

Tags: oracle, debezium, cdc, oracle-cdc

I'm trying to find out the open source solution to capture data change events from OracleDB.
I've read many questions and articles about this question but I do not quite understand which approaches require additional licenses like Oracle GoldenGate.
Currently Debezium supports two modes of capturing data change from OracleDB. First one is using XStreamAPI which explicitly requires GoldenGate license. Second one is using "native LogMiner API". Does second mode require GoldenGate license. And which OracleDB packages supported, does it need express or standard or enterprise edition? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options which do not require license:

1. [OpenLogReplicator](https://github.com/bersler/OpenLogReplicator) - reading directly from redo log files
2. [LogMiner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-logminer-utility.html#GUID-3417B738-374C-4EE3-B15C-3A66E01AE2B5) - reading using database API

Options which do require Oracle GoldenGate (OGG) license:

1. [XStreamAPI](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/XSTRM/xstrm_intro.htm#XSTRM72977)

[OGG license](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/goldengate/core/21.3/ogglc/licensing-information.html#GUID-2BE8732D-B07E-43B6-B9AB-8579E5EFAEAF) is only available for Oracle Database Enterprise Edition:

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So if set-up Debezium to use LogMiner it won't require additional license, yes?

Comment: Yes, https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2442986/is-logminer-tool-licensed

Comment: We don't answer off-topic questions here. Doing so encourages others to ask off-topic questions, hoping that they get an answer before it is closed.